# Can we have micro service architecture for background batch processing?

Tags: architecture, spring-batch, microservices

Recently i developed a spring batch application which has 3 jobs configured in it. Only one jar needs to be deployed to perform three 3 jobs.

If we get another business requirement , I would happily add a new job in existing configuration and it will work fine. We will not create a separate jar for this job.

I was going through some micro service tutorials. I noticed that we create separate code repository for each micro service. 
In spring batch we add all jobs in one jar only though they are independent jobs like small micro services.

My questions is , Should we have micro service kind of architecture or code repository for background batches as well? 
if yes , do we have to create separate repository per job  ?
If not then why ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `In spring batch we add all jobs in one jar`: to whom does `we` refer to here?

Comment: If you are talking microservice Ben already give answer , you always free to choose pragmatic service , here is my book you can find further details - https://github.com/vaquarkhan/microservices-recipes-a-free-gitbook

Answer (score 2):

Packaging multiple independent jobs in a single jar goes against the micro-services approach in the first place. Nothing prevents you from having a single code repository for all jobs, but I would not package them in a single jar for the following reasons:

- Independent lifecyle: If you fix a big in a job, you don't need to redeploy the single monolithic jar that contains all other (unaffected) jobs
- Versioning: Jobs may evolve at different paces. Having a single jar containing different jobs at different versions is not ideal
- Small footprint: Having to deploy a small jar to update a single job is better and more efficient in terms of network usage than transferring a fat jar each time.
- And all other good reasons of making one thing do one thing and do it well

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I think spring batch frameworks / quartz schedulers are designed to have multiple jobs inside single scheduler.  In case of any bugs we only need to make changes for the job which is anyways have its own boundary and will not impact any other job. Anyways thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: No, Spring Batch is not designed for that and is not even concerned with the packaging model, it is up to you to choose how to package your jobs. The monolithic packaging model was the main reason behind deprecating Spring Batch Admin in favour of Spring Cloud Data Flow. You can find the drawbacks of this model as well as the recommended approach (summarised in my answer above) here: https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/MIGRATION.md. Same thing for scheduling, which is not related to the packaging model neither.